# Please correct the following Python CGi program

Tags: python

Please correct the following cgi program

```
#!usr/bin/python

print "Content-type : text/html\n\n"

print "<html><body><span>Hello World</span></body></html>"
```

What is wrong with the above code?

I am getting 500 Internal Server error and it is working through command prompt.

And also please tell me why we need to keep two "\n" in statement

```
print "Content-type : text/html\n\n"
```

Comment: that should be '\r\n'

Comment: I tried with \r\n also but not working

Comment: Is your server configured to run Python?

Comment: Yes it is configured to run with python.

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid HTTP header (no HTTP version declaration, no `Content-Length`, ...). But as Seth`s answer says, 500 = some error with the configuration of your server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While I hope you find your answer, I wanted to give you a heads up, since you're new here. You're not going to get very many upvotes or answers here with this approach to asking questions, as the large majority of SO users don't appreciate being asked to write someone's code for them. I HIGHLY recommend you read this link. It'll be very helpful to you in knowing how to approach questions around here: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: the colon (`:`) should be just after `Content-Type` with no space in the middle, and the `T` in `Type` should be capitalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first line should be

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and if that doesn't work try

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

you have missed **/** before usr

Comment: Thank you it worked but I am getting the output as 

<html><body><span>Hello World</span></body></html>

in browser

And why require \n\n ?

Comment: What output do you want to get? You are getting exactly what you printed.

Comment: I need output as 

Hello World but that is printing with html tags in browser

Comment: Read this and try it http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#introduction

Answer (score 0):

Typically something like a 500 internal error code is generated because of a misconfigured web server.  To run CGI like that, you will need to enable CGI, you will need Python installed, www-data will need to be able to access /usr/bin/python, and www-data will need to be able to access the cgi-script.

If I had to guess, I would say this error is because you don't have CGI enabled, or this script is not in your CGI bin (alternately, one could simply say that the directory that the script is in doesn't have CGI enabled for it).

Comment: I tried with another python program (by downloading from internet) but that program is working. Why above program is not working?

Comment: Could also be permissions on the .py file. If you're running linux try `chmod 755 your_file.py`

Comment: It would be generally better to just make sure that the web server is the owner, and only give them execution privileges.  In most distro's using Apache ( You should be using Apache, CGI like this is somewhat painful under Nginx ) `chown www-data:www-data your_file.py` and then `chmod o=rx`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a program called test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Content-type : text/html\n\n"

print "<html><body><span>Hello World</span></body></html>"
```

Place that program in a cgi-bin subdirectory

```
cgi-bin/test.py
```

Still in the current directory, type:

```
python -m CGIHTTPServer
```

You should now see "Hello World" when pointing your browser to:

```
http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/test.py
```